# Getting Emacs `spacemacs` to accept function that changes latex compiler based upon orgmode header

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I used the latest master version 0.200.10.x `Spacemacs` on emacs 25.3. I was trying to implement a function that is recommended by the `orgmode` [documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#using-xelatex-for-pdf-export) for allowing the user to define which Latex compiler he/she wants to use. I implemented the function but it did not seem to work. The latex compilation step keeps using `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex` as specified in the file header. So I was trying to figure out what adjustment to make.

```
;; Originally taken from Bruno Tavernier: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/31150/focus=31432
;; but adapted to use latexmk 4.20 or higher.
(defun my-auto-tex-cmd ()
  "When exporting from .org with latex, automatically run latex,
     pdflatex, or xelatex as appropriate, using latexmk."
  (let ((texcmd)))
  ;; default command: oldstyle latex via dvi
  (setq texcmd "latexmk -dvi -pdfps -quiet %f")
  ;; pdflatex -> .pdf
  (if (string-match "LATEX_CMD: pdflatex" (buffer-string))
      (setq texcmd "latexmk -pdf -quiet %f"))
  ;; xelatex -> .pdf
  (if (string-match "LATEX_CMD: xelatex" (buffer-string))
      (setq texcmd "latexmk -pdflatex=xelatex -pdf -quiet %f"))
  ;; LaTeX compilation command
  (setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list texcmd)))

(add-hook 'org-export-latex-after-initial-vars-hook 'my-auto-tex-cmd)
```

According to the `Spacemacs` issues [list](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8219) I need to make a change in the `spacemacs-configuration-layers` setting [a la](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/latex#build-command):

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
  (latex :variables latex-build-command "LaTeX"))
```

The problem is that making a change in the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` does not seem to let me apply the change based upon file specific settings.

Does anyone know the right way to implement this function above (`my-auto-tex-cmd`) in spacemacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in a blog [post](http://knl.soba143.net/blog/2015/blog/2015-10-21-xelatex-in-org-mode-8.html) .

The actual elisp code is:

```
;; Default packages included in every tex file, pdflatex or xelatex
(setq org-latex-packages-alist
      '(("" "graphicx" t)
        ("" "longtable" nil)
        ("" "float" nil)))

;; source: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-06/msg00240.html
(defun my-auto-tex-cmd (backend)
  "When exporting from .org with latex,
  automatically run latex, pdflatex, or xelatex as appropriate,
  using latexmk."
  (let ((texcmd))
    (setq texcmd "latexmk -pdf %f")
    (if (string-match "LATEX_CMD: pdflatex" (buffer-string))
        (progn
          (setq texcmd "latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error --shell-escape -synctex=1' %f")
          (setq org-latex-default-packages-alist
                '(("AUTO" "inputenc" t)
                  ("T1"   "fontenc"   t)
                  (""     "fixltx2e"  nil)
                  (""     "wrapfig"   nil)
                  (""     "soul"      t)
                  (""     "textcomp"  t)
                  (""     "marvosym"  t)
                  (""     "wasysym"   t)
                  (""     "latexsym"  t)
                  (""     "amssymb"   t)
                  (""     "hyperref"  nil)))))
    (if (string-match "LATEX_CMD: xelatex" (buffer-string))
        (progn
          (setq texcmd "latexmk -pdflatex='xelatex -file-line-error --shell-escape -synctex=1' -pdf %f")
          (setq org-latex-default-packages-alist
                '(("" "fontspec" t)
                  ("" "xunicode" t)
                  ("" "url" t)
                  ;; ("" "rotating" t)
                  ;; ("" "memoir-article-styles" t)
                  ;; ("american" "babel" t)
                  ;; ("babel" "csquotes" t)
                  ;; ("" "listings" nil)
                  ("svgnames" "xcolor" t)
                  ("" "soul" t)
                  ("xetex, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=FireBrick, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, bookmarksnumbered" "hyperref" nil)
                  ))
          (setq org-latex-classes
                (cons '("memarticle"
                        "\\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}"
                        ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                        ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                        ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                        ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                        ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
                      org-latex-classes))))

    (setq org-latex-pdf-process (list texcmd))))
(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'my-auto-tex-cmd)
```